# Inputs with same name getting problems in Github Actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have this Github Action that uses two different action in the same `job`:

```yaml
name: My workflow

on:
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  my-workflow:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: 1.17

      - name: X Action
        uses: x-action/x-action@main
        with:
          file: x-action.txt

      - name: Y Action
        uses: y-action/y-action@main
        with:
          file: y-action.txt
```

The two inputs `file` cause a problem because Github Actions just consider the first one. Looking inside the composite of Action, they use `${{inputs.<inputs_name>}}`.

I think this is a big problem because a lot of actions use some defaults names in `inputs` like output, path, key.

Maybe there is another way to specify `${{inputs.<inputs_name>}}`, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not gonna be the problem at all.

Composite action has their own `inputs` scope.
The only thing you need to take care of is to use `${{ inputs.file }}` inside the composite actions, not the global `github.inputs.file` - and it will be just all fine.

Comment: Thanks @grzegorz-krukowski  I have tested your point and found another problem. Can I update the answer? My real problem is because I use `$GITHUB_ENV` and I cant update this env, you can check this here: https://github.com/fguisso/test-actions/runs/5530993591?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: Main question is why would you want to do that - messing up with ENV is not a good direction in the first place :)

Comment: This is the real example, I use ENV to construct the final command: https://github.com/projectdiscovery/nuclei-action/blob/main/action.yml